# Django - creating a file and saving in a specific place on server in Linux

Tags: linux, django

I know there are a lot of posts about this topic, but I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

My goal is to create/update a file in the following directory:

`root/my_app_name/main/static/media/images/contact_photos`

My settings.py file looks like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    if DEBUG:
        MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
    #STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static-only")]
        MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
    #MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")]
        STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            #os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
        )
```

Here's what I do now:

```
full_filename = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR + '\main\static\media\images\contact_photos', filename)
with open(full_filename, 'wb+') as f:
        f.write(img_data)
```

I end up with the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/static/media/images/file_name.jpg'
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? I guess, there must be some way of `joining` the file path to BASE_DIR or MEDIA_ROOT, but I can't manage to do this.

Comment: Why `os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR + '\main\static\media\images\contact_photos', filename)` and not `os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '\main\static\media\images\contact_photos', filename)`?

Comment: Also why backslashes and not forward slashes? The arguments for `os.path.join` should be **relative** paths, too.

Comment: Why do you put your django projects direct under `/root`? Is there really a need for that deep directory hierarchy like `root/my_app_name/main/static/media/images/contact_photos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open your python interpreter with the following command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and in the interactive mode try this:

```
from my_app_name import settings
print(settings.BASE_DIR)
```

I'd expect it to return `/root/my_app_name`.

Then in your code you can build up the full path to your file:

```
full_filename = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,
    'main/static/media/images/contact_photos', filename)
```

Assuming that the variable `filename` has the value `file_name.jpg` we should get:

```
/root/my_app_name/main/static/media/images/contact_photos/file_name.jpg
```